# Is it possible to read file from /tmp folder?

Tags: php, html, apache

I am developing a web server using apache in php. I have to read the .ini file from /tmp folder and edit the same and update. so that next time updated values will be read. If file is auto created (first written through program) and read then values are shown properly. If it is already present then not able to read.I have tried changing the permissions and owner settings. why i am not able to read from /tmp folder?

Comment: look at your error_log / error messages. Maybe a base_dir restriction?

Comment: i checked error log. fopen() gives error as : PHP Warning: failed to open stream: Permission denied